# Iterate through array and assign each value

Tags: arrays, iterator, reducers

I need a reducer to iterate through an array and assign each element (2 elements total).  But is my code taking all values and simply assigning it to the key?

For example here:

```
     public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text[]> values,
     OutputCollector<Text, Text[]> output, Reporter reporter)
     throws IOException {
```

Is this method just dumping all my array into the bucket of values?

IS there a way to use a While loop to take each element of the Text[] and assign it to an int?

Here is my start of that:

```
      while (values.hasNext()){
                String AtBats = values.toString();
                int AB = Integer.parseInt(AtBats);
```

This would take every value and make it an AtBat, but I want the second element to be a Hit.  Confused on how to accomplish this.

Comment: What do you mean make it into an AtBat? Do you mean to say it would take every value and make it a string but you want the second element to be an int?

Comment: Sorry I want to take each value and make it into an int.  The snippet I included just shows how I am doing that with the first element in a two element array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I understand from your response you want to take your values and then parse them into a string.

You have everything down but I would suggest for you to inline AtBats and just have it as

```
int AB = Integer.parseInt(values.toString());
```

UPDATE: After talking through this we came down to the conclusion that passing an array and looping through it is superfluous.

Instead of passing an array with two values, then using a while loop to go through it and assign its values to two variables just pass those values down independently.

Comment: What I am confused by is this line in the method:

        Iterator<Text[]> values,

Is values my array?  OR is values all my values associated with the key?

Knowing that will help me figure out what to put in my while loop.

Comment: Ok no need to answer making this more difficult then I should.  Reworking my mapper so I don't need to pass as an array anymore.

Comment: @JPHochbaum so it goes Type and then Variable. In this case your type is Iterator<Text[]> so your values stands for the iterator. And I agree with your second statement. When your code becomes complex it is a good time to question it. Let me know what you end up with.

Comment: Ok so I redid the maapper and it outputs exactly what I need.

WHen I get to my reducer I need to split the comma and space so I could do math.  But I am getting an array out of bounds error, and not sure what I am missing there:

  'while (values.hasNext()){
           //set text to string and delimit
           String v = values.next().toString();
           String[] strings = v.split(", ");
           //set array elements to parameters I need for math
           String AtBats = strings[0];
           String Hits = strings[1];'

Comment: I have no idea how to format code in comments, grrr...  Sorry!

Comment: If you only need the two inputs from the array then why are you looping through it? Make more sense to me to just calculate those variables outside of a loop.

Comment: I have the issue of over thinking this.  So my while loop should split and just assign the inputs to int?  I still get the out of out of bounds error.

Comment: I mean I think it shouldn't even be in an array it seems to me that you have two values that you care about and you are passing those two values from somewhere to this method that right now uses a loop. How about you pass those two values independently into a method and then just use them like that. No while loop. none of that. Just values being passed in as argAtBats and argHits or whatever else you want to name them.

Comment: Sure. Let me know how it goes. I will update my answer to reflect all of this. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: One more question my values are coming in as (400, 40), the atBats and Hits values I need, respectively.  So I need the split method which puts those values into an array minus the comma and space.  So array strings is now [400 40].  Which is why I am trying to asssign the first element to atBats and the second to Hits.  And then doing the math.

I really have no idea any better way to avoid the split method that puts it into an array.

Comment: I would question why you put them together in a string like that first of all. But if you are stuck with that and it is a huge change to make then just pass in the array and without doing a while loop just assign your atBats to be array[0] and your Hits to be array[1]. You don't need a while loop for that.

Comment: This ought to be easier, here is a link to dream in code where my mapper and reducer are, scroll to bottom.  IT wil give you a better idea of why I am putting together as a string.

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/372457-mapping-multiple-values-to-a-key/page__st__15__gopid__2135836&#entry2135836

Comment: After thinking about this more I think I know why my array is out of bounds.  My key is a year and there are multiple lines in my mapper output that have the same year, so more than two array elements are going to be assigned to an array size of 2.

But I am stuck using an array in order to use the split method.